# Is there any way to do a prepared statement with a placeholder in flyway?

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, flyway

It appears if I write this code, for example with Spring Boot

```
CREATE ROLE application WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '${password}';
```

and then set

```
FLYWAY_PLACEHOLDERS_PASSWORD="' DROP table -- "
```

before starting the migration, flyway would execute the injection, as the quoting provided is in the string. Is there a way I can make this a prepared statement, or is there a quoting function I can use to ensure that the value is properly quoted?

Comment: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1500 I've opened this

Comment: Have you tried `quote_literal`? I don't know if PG allows an expression there. Even if not, you could bury it in some dynamic SQL built up and executed inside a `DO` block.

Comment: @jpmc26 I could do that, but then what happens when it's `quote_literal(${password})` and the contents has a `)` in it? since, afaik this is basiclly a template being processed, I'm betting someone clever could get it to execute something. Though that's probably safer for now.

Comment: Also note that there are some trade-offs to consider here. Whoever has the ability to run these commands must already have an account; if it has the appropriate permissions to run other commands as well, they could simply log in and do whatever they please. So this is more an exercise in idiot-proofing than it is in security. You *certainly* shouldn't be triggering a database upgrade system with input from untrusted users.

Comment: @jpmc26 this specific command yes, but this is just the first case I ran into obviously any changeset using a property placeholder no matter what user the changset is run as or could be run as (whether DDL or not) could be injected by way of environment if someone can modify the environment. That of course is unlikely, and I'm not one to judge how possible or probable. This is probably at best a minor security concern as it does rely on another exploit to happen first.

Comment: also tried `quote_literal` there postgres doesn't like it, but that's another question, for another site, imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small improvement over the existing query:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    the_password TEXT := '${password}';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE ROLE application WITH LOGIN PASSWORD %L', the_password);
END
$$
```

Using `format` with `%L` will perform correct escaping for the query. Statements that don't close out the entire `DECLARE`/`BEGIN`/`END` block and the dollar quoted string will result in a parsing error.

This doesn't eliminate all possibilities of injection, but keep in mind the context here. This is a database migration system. I assume that it's not being executed using arbitrary input from untrusted users. It should only be executed by highly trusted users who have access to credentials with the needed privileges to create roles, create/drop tables, etc. As such, this is more an exercise in idiot-proofing, rather than a security mechanism. This query prevents accidents from causing damage; anything that breaks out of this is most likely malicious and would be more easily accomplished if the user bypassed the deployment system entirely.

Comment: so something you aren't considering, is that I'm working with docker on this (which isn't a stated part of the problem), but say you're using docker on docker cloud (currently I am) or kubernetes or whatever, if any part of the system above gets compromised... in all fairness the whole thing might fall over anyways, just saying, that this could limit damage in some ways. of course I may also change, how I'm setting up this user, so that "superuser" perms aren't required by the migration tool. Thanks for the code improvement.

Comment: ultimately my solution is not to parameterize flyway due to its vulnerability.

and for this specific part of the problem I'm using the postgres docker image to load a sql script on first run, with postgres' ability to quote its own variables. https://xenoterracide.com/post/sql-injection-with-spring-boot-and-flyway/